# Enable/Disable ASP.NET MVC Kendo grid custom template controls while Edit and Update

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-grid

Enable/Disable Kendo grid custom template controls while Edit and Update. 
Below code is helps you to Enable/Disable Kendo grid custom template controls

Kendo Grid.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Models.YourModelView>()
    .Name("GridName")
    .DataSource(datasource => datasource
        .Ajax()
        .Model(module =>
        {
            module.Id("ID");
        })
        .Read(read => read.Action("ReadAction", "YourController"))
        .Create(create => create.Action("CreateAction", "YourController"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("EditAction", "YourController"))
    )
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.ID).Hidden();
        columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Title("Prefix");
        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); });
    })
    .Editable(editable =>
    {
        editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("_AddNewCorporateGroup").Window(w => w.Title("Add/Update").Width(600));
    })
    .Events(e => e.Edit("onEdit"))
)
```

JavaScript Method.

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var kendoWindow = e.container.data("GridName");
    if (e.model.isNew()) {
        $('#Custom template Controller Name').fadeIn();
    } else {

        $('#Custom template Controller Name').fadeOut();
    }
}
```

Comment: `today I'm posting answer` What is your question? Or, are you writing a blog in SO?

Comment: Are you asking how to optionally enable/disable a custom template applied to a column of a grid, like two edit templates?